# Trying to delete using Mutation but its giving the error saying authorsCollection.delete is not a function

Tags: graphql, relay, graphql-js

When I try to run it, It is giving me the error.Trying to delete using Mutation but its giving the error saying "authorsCollection.delete" is not a function

```
const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Mutations",
  fields: {
    DeleteAuthor: {
      type: Author,
      args: {
        _id: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
        name: {type: GraphQLString},

      },
      resolve: function(rootValue, args) {
        let author = Object.assign({}, args);
        console.log(args);
        return authorsCollection.delete(author._id)
          .then(_ => author);
      }
    }
```

What should be edited in the code so that I can implemented the Delete operation?

It is giving me the error as below

```
{
  "data": {
    "DeleteAuthor": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "authorsCollection.delete is not a function",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `authorsCollection` from? How do you import or create it in your code? Can you show the related code?

Comment: Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/2w1kcrtq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `authorsCollection.delete is not a function` indicates that `authorsCollection` does not have any function named `delete`. In your jsfiddle code, I see you have used promised-mongo library. The API to remove documents is [`remove`](https://github.com/gordonmleigh/promised-mongo#dbcollectionremovequery-justone-callback), not `delete`.

Change to

```
authorsCollection.remove({_id: ObjectId(author._id)})
```

The `_id` passed is a string. But the `_id` property of author in DB is of type `ObjectID`. So, you have to convert it to `ObjectID` type. You do so by using `promised-mongo`'s `ObjectId`. So, import it in the beginning:

```
import {ObjectId} from 'promised-mongo';
```

Comment: I have done authorsCollection.remove({id:author._id}). It is not showing any error but now It does not get deleted from database.

Comment: @chyangba, I forgot to convert `_id` to object ID of MongoDB. I have updated my answer. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I am doing as your updated answer, now it shows the error "ObjectId is not defined". I have already imported ObjectId from promised-mongo and it still showing me the error.

Comment: How did you import ObjectId from promised-mongo?

Comment: import {ObjectId} from 'promised-mongo';